# Optimal way of sharing load between worker threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, multithreading, deno

What is the optimal way of sharing linear tasks between worker threads to improve performance?

Take the following example of a basic Deno web-server:

**Main Thread**

```
// Create an array of four worker threads
const workers = new Array<Worker>(4).fill(
    new Worker(new URL("./worker.ts", import.meta.url).href, {
        type: "module",
    })
);

for await (const req of server) {
    // Pass this request to worker a worker thread
}
```

**worker.ts**

```
self.onmessage = async (req) => {
  //Peform some linear task on the request and make a response
};
```

Would the optimal way of distributing tasks be something along the lines of this?

```
function* generator(): Generator<number> {
    let i = 0;
    while (true) {
        i == 3 ? (i = 0) : i++;
        yield i;
    }
}

const gen = generator();

const workers = new Array<Worker>(4).fill(
    new Worker(new URL("./worker.ts", import.meta.url).href, {
        type: "module",
    })
);

for await (const req of server) {
    // Pass this request to a worker thread
    workers[gen.next().value].postMessage(req);
}
```

Or is there a better way of doing this? Say, for example, using Attomics to determine which threads are free to accept another task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When working with WorkerThread code like this, I found that the best way to distribute jobs was to have the WorkerThread ask the main thread for a job when the WorkerThread knew that it was done with the prior job.  The main thread could then send it a new job in response to that message.

In the main thread, I maintained a queue of jobs and a queue of WorkerThreads waiting for a job.  If the job queue was empty, then the WorkerThread queue would likely have some workerThreads in it waiting for a job.  Then, any time a job is added to the job queue, the code checks to see if there's a workerThread waiting and, if so, removes it from the queue and sends it the next job.

Anytime a workerThread sends a message indicating it is ready for the next job, then we check the job queue.  If there's a job there, it is removed and sent to that worker.  If not, the worker is added to the WorkerThread queue.

This whole bit of logic was very clean, did not need atomics or shared memory (because everything was gated through the event loop of the main process) and wasn't very much code.

I arrived at this mechanism after trying several other ways that each had their own problems.  In one case, I had concurrency issues, in another I was starving the event loop, in another, I didn't have proper flow control to the WorkerThreads and was overwhelming them and not distributing load equally.

Comment: This is a really good answer! Could you update it with a modified version of the example to illustrate your solution to future viewers?

Comment: Also, is there not an overhead cost in passing high quantities of messages between worker threads? In the case of getting many requests at once, would Atomics not be faster?

Comment: @Eidolon - Just sending messages to/from Worker Threads is quick.  But, if you are sending lots of data with those messages, then it will (by default) have to be copied and some use of shared memory might improve performance.  It really depends upon what you're doing.

Comment: @Eidolon - I personally find it easier to coordinate threads in Javascript through the event queue instead of using atomics (I find it more foolproof and easier to design bug-free code).  Atomics are needed if multiple threads want access to the same data (in shared memory), but not required if you hand-off data to a thread and only one thread is ever working on a given piece of data.

Comment: @Eidolon - FYI, [this file](https://github.com/jfriend00/crypto-random-test/blob/master/read-speed.js#L16) contains a `WorkerList` class that, instead of a job queue, uses promises.  Code that has a job to do does `const worker = await workerList.get();` and when that resolves, it has a worker that it can send a job to.  Workers get put into the workerList when they signal they are done with their job or when first created.

Answer (score 0):

There are some abstractions in Deno to handle these kind of needs very easily. Especially considering the [`pooledMap`](https://deno.land/std@0.173.0/async/pool.ts?s=pooledMap) functionality.

So you have a `server` which is an async iterator and you would like to leverage threading to generate responses since each response depends on a time taking heavy computation right..?

Simple.

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts";
import { pooledMap } from "https://deno.land/std@0.173.0/async/pool.ts";

const server = serve({ port: 8000 }),
      ress   = pooledMap( window.navigator.hardwareConcurrency - 1
                        , server
                        , req => new Promise(v => v(respondWith(req))
                        );

for await (const res of ress) {
  // respond with res
}
```

That's it. In this particular case the `repondWith` function bears the heavy calculation to prepare your response object. In case it's already an async function then you don't even need to wrap it into a promise. Obviously here I have just used available many less one threads but it's up to you to decide howmany threads to spawn.

Comment: A someone who spent quite some time with JS and NodeJS this `pooledMap` still makes to sense to me as well as the documentation on it. What exactly does it do and why should we use it? Where does `respondWith` come from? I assume your code somehow shifts some load for `req` onto separate threads but this code is very unclear to me.

Comment: @Telion In order to use pooledMap you need async iterators such as the  `serve` function  of Deno that gives us the `server` async iterable in the above code. Now `server` gives requests one after the other as they arrive asymchronously but while we are processing the request to prepare a response (in the `respondWith` dummy function) another request may arrive. So pooledMap puts them into seperate threads and hen joins the obtained responses back under a new aync iterable.

Comment: Kind of makes sense now, thank you. But in your example you're iterating through the pooled map with an await for, wouldn't that forever block the further code execution? So to proceed we have to break out the loop, right?

Comment: @Telion The point here is, we are responding to the received requests as they keep arriving. The `for await (const res of ress)` loop turns once when a received request is processed and a response is prepared. It's basically a http(s) server which are known to be running indefinitelly. Having said that you can always use the `break` keyword in the loop once a condition is satisfied.